# Email notification icon for panel

Tags: 10.10, indicator, email, notification

The standard *Indicator Applet 0.4.6* on a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.10 doesn't achieve what I am looking for.

Can someone recommend an alternative applet to notify when new emails arrive. It should have the following features:

- IMAP support.
- Multiple mailboxes.

Bonus features:

- Calendar notifications.
- Push IMAP support.
- Customisable icons & visuals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Note:** Popper is not longer developed. The last working version is for 12.04. Later releases are not supported.

You may want to have a look a [Popper](https://launchpad.net/popper), a nice and actively developed project by @RalfHersel.

Comment: Thanks, popper is everything I wanted. Accepted this answer because you got there first!

Comment: In fact @Allan was first (40s earlier)

Comment: whats 40s between friends ;)

Comment: @Allan: nothing (almost) - good you're still around!

Comment: Is popper still a good choice? seems like it is not updated since 2010

Comment: @Woeistg Sadly the development of Popper was discontinued, and it will not work in releases later than 12.04.

Answer (score 4):

**Popper**

I would suggest popper as a good replacement as it can deal with POP & IMAP and multiple accounts popper is not in the Software Center you need to install it from a .deb package with can be downloded from there launchpad page [here](https://edge.launchpad.net/popper)

Hope this helps