# How to make Thunderbird notify of new email like Evolution?

Tags: indicator, evolution, thunderbird, notification

In Ubuntu when new mail arrives *Evolution* changes message indicator to green color. I have migrated from *Evolution* to *Thunderbird* and that is why looking for how to make *Thunderbird* react like *Evolution* once a new mail arrives.

**UPDATE 1**

I have forgotten to note that I don't have *administrator privileges* in my working computer.

Thanks

Comment: you also may have a look at [Popper](http://askubuntu.com/q/28231)

Answer (score 6):

There is an extension that integrates Thunderbird with the Ubuntu Messaging menu (and also provides NotifyOSD notifications) that comes in a PPA. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

To install it in Ubuntu, use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ruben-verweij/thunderbird-indicator
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xul-ext-indicator libnotify-bin
```

You'll then find it in the Thunderbird extensions. The PPA provides packages for Ubuntu 10.10 and 11.04, though the 11.04 version is a bit more advanced and allows you only display notifications for messages that arrive in a certain folder, etc.

There was also an add-on for Thunderbird, based on the above extension, but it has since been removed.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have administrator privileges.

Comment: Besides it works only with Ubuntu Unity as it is mentioned in its mozilla add-ons page.

Comment: They are wrong, it works fine in a normal GNOME session. All you need is the indicator-messages menu and your system got to be 32-bit.

Comment: I have 64 bit OS in addition to all these problems.

Comment: I used that and it throws up knows issues. The problem is that probably of some issues in packaging. `libnotify-bin` should be a dependency for `xul-ext-indicator` I for got the libnotify-bin and used to get error every now and then

Comment: ppa doesnt exist

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use [popper](https://edge.launchpad.net/popper). This is an e-mail checker applications, and it can start Thunderbird too.

Answer (score 1):

In latest releases of Ubuntu - 12.04 and later, Thunderbird is default mail-client and by default, notifies of new mail.

So, I would suggest upgrading to 12.04 or 12.10.

[image]

[image]

---

For details on how to configure notifications for selected Folders in Thunderbird please refer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177127/how-to-configure-thunderbird-to-notify-new-mails-only-in-certain-folders).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you need but I have used [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/xultray-for-gecko-192/) addon of thunderbird which minimizes to tray and gives pop up notification for new messages.