# How to disable OSD notifications for specific email addresses?

Tags: thunderbird, notify-osd

I receive several logs per day via email, either from testing operations, server status or backup resumes.

Can I some how disable the [notification balloon](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD) either by a specific email address, the email subject or any other possible filter, as to not be constantly notified about the success operations?

I've looked within the [Notify OSD Configuration](https://askubuntu.com/q/13464/63174), but couldn't find any option to this end.

*Since the email comes with different information when errors occur, I already have filters within Thunderbird as to move error logs to a folder that I keep tabs on...*

<sup>If relevant, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 fully updated, and Thunderbird 15.0.1.</sup>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While this solution does not work with configurations for OSD notifications, you can deal with your issue within the filters you've setup on Thunderbird.

Since the email notifications presented by OSD refer to unread messages, you can add to your filter the option `Mark as Read`.

[image]

This will prevent those messages from being presented by the OSD notification, thus solving your initial issue.

Answer (score 4):

try this add on

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla

you can suppress notifications using filters

Comment: the addon says it works... it shows new options in the filters menu, but sadly it has no effect. >:(   so I still have no solution for this. (thunderbird 24.6.0, filtaquilla 1.2.0)

Comment: I needed to restart Thunderbird after configuring filtaquilla, then it worked. (Tunderbird 68.2.2, filtaquilla 2.0)

Answer (score -1):

See this answer as well, which suggests unsubscribing from certain folders (for example, if you use Gmail to filter into folders).

[How to configure Thunderbird to notify new mails only in certain folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177127/how-to-configure-thunderbird-to-notify-new-mails-only-in-certain-folders)

I tried to use filtaquilla, but it would have required me to add a lot of folders.

Personally, I don't like the "Mark as read" option, because I haven't read them.  I do like to look at mailing lists, but I hate them interrupting me when I am working.

Comment: I tried this... it breaks IMAP. It will only let you see those folders at all if they are subscribed... it doesn't just disable notifications. (eg. my mailling list filters failed and auto-disabled since the folder is gone)

Comment: But I agree, "mark as read" is a horrible option to use.

Comment: I don't have the same problem @Peter - my folders are still there despite being unsubscribed.  However - I do my filtering on Gmail and use thunderbird to make a local backup of my mail.