# Thunderbird gmail with priority inbox?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

Is it possible to get thunderbird to show the [Gmail]/Important as the default inbox?

If so, how?

Comment: This should answer your question.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/177127/how-to-configure-thunderbird-to-notify-new-mails-only-in-certain-folders

Answer (score 1):

[Folderpane Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/folderpane-tools/) add-on should allow you to override startup folder.

Can you give it a try and confirm if it fix your issue?

Comment: Nope. That's just the startup folder. I want no notification coming from anything other than the important folder.