# Email Client which runs in background and notifies when email arrives

Tags: thunderbird, email, notification

I am new in Ubuntu and currently running `16.04-beta2` release. I have configured Thunderbird Email client for everyday use and the only problem with Thunderbird is that it doesn't run in background and I get no notification when any mail arrives. I have to minimize Thunderbird and check time to time to get notified about my mail which is pretty disgusting and time consuming.

So, I am searching for an Email Client which works great with Ubuntu, runs in background when minimized and give notifications when mail arrives. Any kind soul to help me out with proper information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Thunderbird notify of new email like Evolution?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29639/how-to-make-thunderbird-notify-of-new-email-like-evolution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to quit Thunderbird. It's got plenty of addons for almost everything and there's a nice one just for your case:

https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/thunderbird/addon/mailbox-alert/

It's got configuration for everything you might need. You can set a number of seconds to display that notification window, even large one for like 12 hours.
Also check **MinimizeToTray** addon.

Comment: FireTray is another choice, but unfortunately it has been discontinued. But it still works for me with Thunderbird 45 on Ubuntu Gnome xenial.